# Mongo Auth Provider doesn't inject user object in routing context after authentification in vert.x 4.2.5

Tags: java, reactive-programming, vert.x

i'm using **vert.x** 4.2.5, and mongodb as auth provider.

the problem that even after logging in successfully, the user still can't access to the private routes, and i can't find the **user object** injected in **routing context**

my api :

```
Router apiAuth = Router.router(vertx);

SessionStore store = LocalSessionStore.create(vertx);
SessionHandler sessionHandler = SessionHandler.create(store);

apiAuth.route().handler(sessionHandler);
apiAuth.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());

AuthenticationHandler basicAuthHandler = BasicAuthHandler.create(authenticationProvider);

apiAuth.post("/login").handler(this::login);
apiAuth.get("/checkLogin").handler(basicAuthHandler);
apiAuth.get("/checkLogin").handler(this::checkLogin);
```

**Login method :**

```
  private void login(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    JsonObject body = routingContext.getBodyAsJson();
    JsonObject authInfo =
        new JsonObject()
            .put("username", body.getString("username"))
            .put("password", body.getString("password"));
    authenticationProvider
      .authenticate(authInfo).onSuccess(user -> {
        routingContext
          .response()
          .setStatusCode(200)
          .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
          .end(
            new JsonObject()
              .put("success", true)
              .encode());
      });
  }
```

**checkLogin method :**

```
  private void checkLogin(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    routingContext.response().setStatusCode(200).end(new JsonObject().put("authenticated", true).encode());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use session for such kind of operations.
 When you put/add authenticated user data to routing context it's relevancy is **only** as long as this specific context/request is live, when the context ends the data added to it dies with it.
 So when you want to save your authenticated user data for next **new** request you need to save it in the session instance.
You can achieve this like this:

```
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.ext.auth.User;
import io.vertx.ext.auth.impl.UserImpl;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;
...

// in your authenticationProvider
public void authenticate(RoutingContext context, Handler<AsyncResult<User>> handler) {
  .
  your code to authenticate the user...
  .
  JsonObject userData = new JsonObject();
  userData.put("id", 123456);
  userData.put("name", "userName");
  User user = new UserImpl(userData, new JsonObject());
  context.session().put("user", user); // to add user data to the session
  handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(user));
}

private void checkLogin(RoutingContext context) {
  User user = context.session().get("user"); // to get user data from the session
  if (user == null) {
    //user needs authentication
  }
}
```